# How can I send url api from aspnet core server to my angular2 singleapp?

Tags: url, angular, asp.net-web-api, typescript, asp.net-core

I would like send my url of the web api (different server, different domain...) from my asp net core server to my client angular2. 
For the moment I store my settings in typescript config file in my angular2 app.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

> For the moment I store my settings in typescript config file in my angular2 app.

This is the way to go.

## Alternative

Add another endpoint that you can query to get the config which will contain the endpoint you are looking for (and possibly other stuff).

Comment: Ok, but I want detect automatically if the app is in prod mode or dev mode for change the api url without comment line in my code before publish my project in production. Any idea how can I do that?